# JAVA using JFXPanel in JFrame with mouse listener

Tags: java, swing, javafx

Currently having an issue where I cannot get my JFrame and associated JFXPanel to pop up/display. I have looked at numerous other examples on this site and others of using JFXPanels with JFrames but all are quite different than mine. I believe my issue may lie in the fact that I am using two consecutive runnables so maybe the JavaFX thread hasnt finished by the time the Swing thread tries to use components from it? Help would be greatly appreciated- relevant code below:

Note: I am not receiving any compilation or runtime errors. My issue is that nothing happens when I would like my dialog to pop

```
 @Override
protected void onMouseDown(MouseButton button,
                           KeyModifier keyModifier,
                           int mouseX,
                           int mouseY) {
    try {
        if (MouseButton.LEFT.equals(button)) {

            FeatureWrapper closestStationOrSpanFw = SelectionUtil.getClosestSpanOrStation(toMapPoint(mouseX,
                                                                                                     mouseY));
            if (closestStationOrSpanFw != null) {
                IGeometry shape = closestStationOrSpanFw.getIFeature().getShapeCopy();
                if (shape instanceof Point) {
                    final Point point = (Point) shape;
                    GeometryUtil.projectLatLong(point);
                    final JFXPanel panel = new JFXPanel();

                    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            WebView webView = new WebView();
                            webView.getEngine().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                            try {
                                webView.getEngine().load(
                                        "http://arcgissrv:35200/woViewer/StreetView/streetview.html?y=" + point.getY() + "&x=" + point
                                                .getX());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            Scene scene = new Scene(webView);
                            panel.setScene(scene);
                        }
                    });

                    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                            frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
                            frame.pack();
                            frame.setVisible(true);
                        }
                    });

                    .........
```

stacktrace from error received when using a suggested solution below:

```
EDT violation detected
javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@a230a7,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.checkThreadViolations(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:75)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.addDirtyRegion(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:66)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4793)
at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3297)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setBorder(JComponent.java:1800)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(SynthStyle.java:913)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SynthLookAndFeel.java:265)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.updateStyle(SynthPanelUI.java:117)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installDefaults(SynthPanelUI.java:100)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(BasicPanelUI.java:56)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installUI(SynthPanelUI.java:62)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:153)
at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.createGlassPane(JRootPane.java:545)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:365)
at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(JFrame.java:277)
at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:258)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.<init>(FXBrowser.java:36)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.showBrowser(FXBrowser.java:22)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.StreetViewTool.onMouseDown(StreetViewTool.java:99)
at cc.nisc.mapping.esri.controls.core.NiscTool.onMouseDown(NiscTool.java:135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.ObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.handleVtblInvokeCallbackNative(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy$0.run(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.b(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.post(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.executeVtblCallback(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.runMessagePump(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

EDT violation detected
javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@dd79e7,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.checkThreadViolations(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:75)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.addDirtyRegion(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:66)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4793)
at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3297)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setBorder(JComponent.java:1800)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(SynthStyle.java:913)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SynthLookAndFeel.java:265)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.updateStyle(SynthPanelUI.java:117)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installDefaults(SynthPanelUI.java:100)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(BasicPanelUI.java:56)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installUI(SynthPanelUI.java:62)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:153)
at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.createContentPane(JRootPane.java:520)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:367)
at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(JFrame.java:277)
at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:258)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.<init>(FXBrowser.java:36)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.showBrowser(FXBrowser.java:22)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.StreetViewTool.onMouseDown(StreetViewTool.java:99)
at cc.nisc.mapping.esri.controls.core.NiscTool.onMouseDown(NiscTool.java:135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.ObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.handleVtblInvokeCallbackNative(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy$0.run(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.b(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.post(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.executeVtblCallback(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.runMessagePump(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

EDT violation detected
    javax.swing.JLayeredPane[null.layeredPane,0,0,0x0,invalid,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=,flags=0,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=,optimizedDrawingPossible=true]
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.checkThreadViolations(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:75)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.addDirtyRegion(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:66)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4793)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4808)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.setLayer(JLayeredPane.java:374)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.setLayer(JLayeredPane.java:345)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:225)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:625)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:367)
at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(JFrame.java:277)
at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:258)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.<init>(FXBrowser.java:36)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.showBrowser(FXBrowser.java:22)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.StreetViewTool.onMouseDown(StreetViewTool.java:99)
at cc.nisc.mapping.esri.controls.core.NiscTool.onMouseDown(NiscTool.java:135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.ObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.handleVtblInvokeCallbackNative(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy$0.run(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.b(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.post(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.executeVtblCallback(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.runMessagePump(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

EDT violation detected
   javax.swing.JPanel[null.contentPane,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$1,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@dd79e7,flags=1,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.checkThreadViolations(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:75)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.addDirtyRegion(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:66)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4793)
at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3297)
at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(JLayeredPane.java:232)
at java.awt.Container.add(Container.java:966)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.setContentPane(JRootPane.java:625)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:367)
at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(JFrame.java:277)
at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:258)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.<init>(FXBrowser.java:36)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.showBrowser(FXBrowser.java:22)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.StreetViewTool.onMouseDown(StreetViewTool.java:99)
at cc.nisc.mapping.esri.controls.core.NiscTool.onMouseDown(NiscTool.java:135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.ObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.handleVtblInvokeCallbackNative(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy$0.run(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.b(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.post(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.executeVtblCallback(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.runMessagePump(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

EDT violation detected
javax.swing.JRootPane[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=javax.swing.JRootPane$RootLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@4709b1,flags=1,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.checkThreadViolations(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:75)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.addDirtyRegion(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:66)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4793)
at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3297)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setBorder(JComponent.java:1800)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(SynthStyle.java:913)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SynthLookAndFeel.java:265)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthRootPaneUI.updateStyle(SynthRootPaneUI.java:94)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthRootPaneUI.installDefaults(SynthRootPaneUI.java:59)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicRootPaneUI.installUI(BasicRootPaneUI.java:56)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.setUI(JRootPane.java:473)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.updateUI(JRootPane.java:483)
at javax.swing.JRootPane.<init>(JRootPane.java:370)
at javax.swing.JFrame.createRootPane(JFrame.java:277)
at javax.swing.JFrame.frameInit(JFrame.java:258)
at javax.swing.JFrame.<init>(JFrame.java:181)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.<init>(FXBrowser.java:36)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.showBrowser(FXBrowser.java:22)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.StreetViewTool.onMouseDown(StreetViewTool.java:99)
at cc.nisc.mapping.esri.controls.core.NiscTool.onMouseDown(NiscTool.java:135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.ObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.handleVtblInvokeCallbackNative(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy$0.run(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.b(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.post(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.executeVtblCallback(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.runMessagePump(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

EDT violation detected
 javax.swing.JPanel[,0,0,0x0,invalid,layout=java.awt.FlowLayout,alignmentX=0.0,alignmentY=0.0,border=javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthBorder@1cd75df,flags=9,maximumSize=,minimumSize=,preferredSize=]
at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1589)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.checkThreadViolations(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:75)
at cc.nisc.gui.CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.addDirtyRegion(CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager.java:66)
at javax.swing.JComponent.repaint(JComponent.java:4793)
at java.awt.Component.repaint(Component.java:3297)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setBorder(JComponent.java:1800)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthStyle.installDefaults(SynthStyle.java:913)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthLookAndFeel.updateStyle(SynthLookAndFeel.java:265)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.updateStyle(SynthPanelUI.java:117)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installDefaults(SynthPanelUI.java:100)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicPanelUI.installUI(BasicPanelUI.java:56)
at javax.swing.plaf.synth.SynthPanelUI.installUI(SynthPanelUI.java:62)
at javax.swing.JComponent.setUI(JComponent.java:664)
at javax.swing.JPanel.setUI(JPanel.java:153)
at javax.swing.JPanel.updateUI(JPanel.java:126)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:86)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:109)
at javax.swing.JPanel.<init>(JPanel.java:117)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.initComponents(FXBrowser.java:52)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.<init>(FXBrowser.java:37)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.FXBrowser.showBrowser(FXBrowser.java:22)
at cc.nisc.mapping.controls.tools.StreetViewTool.onMouseDown(StreetViewTool.java:99)
at cc.nisc.mapping.esri.controls.core.NiscTool.onMouseDown(NiscTool.java:135)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.ObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.handleVtblInvokeCallbackNative(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy$0.run(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.b(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.post(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.a(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjectProxy.executeVtblCallback(Unknown Source)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.NativeObjRef.runMessagePump(Native Method)
at com.esri.arcgis.interop.STAThread.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `FXBrowser` class to show a webpage in `JavaFX WebView`.Coz I'm using this in one of my Project

You can use this by calling

```
FXBrowser.showBrowser("url you want to show");
```

The **FXBrowser** class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class FXBrowser extends JFrame {

    private JPanel webViewPanel;
    private final JavaFXBrowser browser;
    private String url;
    private static FXBrowser fxbrowser;

    public static void showBrowser(String url) {
        if (fxbrowser == null) {
            fxbrowser = new FXBrowser();
        }
        if (fxbrowser.isVisible()) {
            return;
        }
        fxbrowser.url = url;
        fxbrowser.setVisible(true);
        fxbrowser.loadPanel();
    }

    public static void showBrowser() {
        showBrowser("http://www.bing.com");
    }

    private FXBrowser() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(1024, 600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Browser");
        browser = new JavaFXBrowser();
        webViewPanel.add(browser.getComponent(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        browser.load();
    }

    public void loadPanel() {
        browser.setUrl(url);
    }

    private void initComponents() {
        webViewPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        webViewPanel.setLayout(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
        getContentPane().add(webViewPanel, java.awt.BorderLayout.CENTER);
        pack();
    }
}

class JavaFXBrowser {

    JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
    WebEngine webEngine;
    WebView webView;

    public void load() {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { // this will run initFX as JavaFX-Thread
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView = new WebView();
                fxPanel.setScene(new Scene(webView));
                webEngine = webView.getEngine();
            }
        });
    }

    public Component getComponent() {
        return fxPanel;
    }

    public void setUrl(final String url) {
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() { // this will run initFX as JavaFX-Thread
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webEngine.load(url);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Sample Usage**

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main extends JFrame {

    public Main() {
        JButton button = new JButton("OOPs");
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                FXBrowser.showBrowser("http://demo.borland.com/gmopost/");
            }
        });
        add(button);
        pack();
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: receiving an edt violation error after copy/pasting the class in and calling using FXBrowser.showBrowser("http://arcgissrv:35200/woViewer/StreetView/streetview.html?y=34.718066617272415&x=-87.78988680543897");   If i throw it in a runnable then the i get an empty window

Comment: @peggyLeggy Can you post the full stack trace of that error

Comment: I have fixed the error however The FXBrowser still shows empty for the URL posted above, however if i use this url it is OK (I need to use the first URL the 2nd wont be acceptable): https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=600x300&location=40.201316987470086,-83.98099300983233

Comment: so, just to be clear, still receiving no errors and still have an empty JFrame

Comment: I went ahead and posted the stack trace of the  edt violation error that I get if i don't put your FXBrowser.showBrowser () call in a Runnable, check the edited post

Comment: are you getting a white colored or grey colored frame.coz white colored means webview is loaded.else the issue is that webview is not at all loaded..and try to resize the jframe coz sometimes it loads after rezize or repaint

Comment: starts white and turns grey almost immediately

Comment: you are using Platform.runLater or SwingUtilities.invokeLater to show the browser

Comment: SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Comment: Try using Platform.runLater

Comment: I receive a Toolkit not initialized error with Platform.runLater

Comment: Have you checked with other websites?

Comment: I went ahead and accepted. your fxbrowser class does work. It looks as if my specific url (which is fine when opened in a browser normally) is causing issues when called from code. Thanks for your help